# Slow down search when many updates for Postresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, indexing

I noticed a problem that when there are a lot of updates on table then searching in that table slows down significantly.

My table looks more or less like that(with few more jsondb column):
`ID | PRODUCT_ID | ATTRIBUTES(jsondb) | CATEGORY_ID`

The table has around 30 milion rows and size 100GB
There is an index created for CATEGORY_ID column.

When I perform such a query when there is no load on table it takes few seconds
`SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM TABLE WHERE CATEGORY_ID='1234'`

When a lots of updates are performed then it takes from 20 minutes to 1 hour.

Is there any explanation why it happens ? I need to mention that I am no database expert. We have a DB team in our company. They suggest to create another table with PRODUCT_ID, CATEGORY_ID where there won't be so much updates.

Do you know any other solutions to that problem and why it happens in the first place ?

Thank you in advance for help :)

Comment: Read this [Slow Query Questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions#Guide_to_Asking_Slow_Query_Questions) and add the listed information to your question.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the the index not being balanced correclty after so many updates. Maybe a reorganization could help. Other possible solution would use a covering index with (category_id, product_id). However, it's unclear to me how beneficial this solution could be. Please retrieve the execution plan WHEN THE QUERY IS SLOW, and add it to this question.

Comment: Does the performance recover as soon as the updates stop?  Also, what version?